# QProcess does not work if the path in argument list has a whitespace

Tags: c++, qt

I want to execute following command using `QProcess`, that works in `cmd` already if executed:

```
C:\\myApplication\\tools\\dcmodify.exe -v -ie -gin -nb -ma (0010,0010)=TestedData "C:\Users\user.name\Documents\My Tools Data\Temp\Demo Phantom Skin\dicom\*"
```

The first argument, which gives the path of the executable is defined as a `QString`:

```
    QString srcToolPath = QDir::toNativeSeparators(QDir::cleanPath(qApp->applicationDirPath() + Constants::TOOLS_PATH + QDir::separator() + toQString("dcmodify.exe")));
```

The argument list and path, where the executable should be executed, is defined as a `QStringList`:

```
QString dstDicomPath = QDir::cleanPath(Utilities::getTempPath() + QDir::separator() + toQString("Anon_") + QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString(Constants::DETAILED_DATE_TIME_FORMAT)) + QDir::separator();

QStringList argumentList;
argumentList <<
toQString(" -v") <<
toQString(" -ie") <<
toQString(" -gin") <<
toQString(" -nb") <<
toQString(" -ma (0010,0010)=TestedData") << 
toQString(" \"") + QDir::toNativeSeparators(dstDicomPath) + toQString("*\"");
```

and the process is started:

```
QProcess anonymizerProcess;
anonymizerProcess.start(srcToolPath, argumentList);
```

Since the `dstDicomPath` contains some whitespaces, I added quotes around it. Although the command is executed, somehow I don't get the result like in `cmd`. What I am doing wrong with `dstDicomPath` string?

Comment: I hope I am not mistaken, but Qt probably takes care about spaces itself. If the program or an argument contains space, then the whole argument is enclosed into quotes. So you probably do not need to handle the quotes yourself. Not in program path and not in arguments. But on the other hand this `" -ma (0010,0010)=TestedData"` should be passed as two arguments and without the space at the beginning. So `... << "-ma" << "(0010,0010)=TestedData" << ...`. Btw what is this function `toQString`? What does it do? Why are you using it at all?

Comment: Btw. if you already have the whole command string `C:\\myApplication\\tools\\dcmodify.exe -v -ie -gin -nb -ma (0010,0010)=TestedData "C:\Users\user.name\Documents\My Tools Data\Temp\Demo Phantom Skin\dicom\*"` and want to check how it is split to individual tokens for passing to `QProcess::start()` then you can use `QProcess::splitCommand()`.

Comment: The quotes should be added to the path, otherwise the spaces will be suggested as the next part of the path as a 2nd parameter passed to the call to start.

Comment: You misunderstood my point. Of course I know that in the command you need to quote the path or args which conatin space. But I am saying that Qt adds the quotes automatically when needed. You do not need to care about it. And that is the reason why it requires splitting `program` and `arguments` and does not accept the whole command as a single space-separated string. With the splitting to `program` and `arguments` (as `QStringList`) Qt exactly knows where to put the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

OK, there are multiple unknowns, for example what `toQString()` does in your code, but nevermind. Let's start with the assumption that this command is correct and would work if you called it from the command line:

```
C:\myApplication\tools\dcmodify.exe -v -ie -gin -nb -ma (0010,0010)=TestedData "C:\Users\user.name\Documents\My Tools Data\Temp\Demo Phantom Skin\dicom\*"
```

now lets have a look at what `QProcess::splitCommand()` returns (note that I escaped the backslashes and quotes in the command by prepending backslash):

```
QString cmd= "C:\\myApplication\\tools\\dcmodify.exe -v -ie -gin -nb -ma (0010,0010)=TestedData \"C:\\Users\\user.name\\Documents\\My Tools Data\\Temp\\Demo Phantom Skin\\dicom\\*\"";
qDebug() << QProcess::splitCommand(cmd);
```

It displays

```
("C:\\myApplication\\tools\\dcmodify.exe", "-v", "-ie", "-gin", "-nb", "-ma", "(0010,0010)=TestedData", "C:\\Users\\user.name\\Documents\\My Tools Data\\Temp\\Demo Phantom Skin\\dicom\\*")
```

... and this is exactly what you need to pass to the `program` and `arguments` for calling `QProcess::start()`. Hence:

```
auto program = QString("C:\\myApplication\\tools\\dcmodify.exe");
auto arguments = QStringList() << "-v" << "-ie" << "-gin" << "-nb" 
                               << "-ma" << "(0010,0010)=TestedData" 
                               << "C:\\Users\\user.name\\Documents\\My Tools Data\\Temp\\Demo Phantom Skin\\dicom\\*";
QProcess process;
process.start(program, arguments);
```

So the message here is that you do not need to try to fix the quotes about whitespaced strings yourself. Qt does it for you automatically. All you need is to correctly split the program and arguments so that Qt knows where to put quotes.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation but still my problem exist, cause of `QString dstDicomPath`  if that string does not double quoted with  `toQString(" \"") + QDir::toNativeSeparators(dstDicomPath) + toQString("*\"");` It does not work. But the `toQString(" \"") ` insert a back slash into the path such: \"C:\Users\user.name\Documents\My Tools Data\Temp\Demo Phantom Skin\dicom\*" . What in argument list needed is: "C:\Users\user.name\Documents\My Tools Data\Temp\Demo Phantom Skin\dicom\*"